# NullPointerException error in Hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, hashmap, null-pointer

I have spent countless hours on this one part of my code which is giving me a Null Pointer Exception. I do not understand why it is happening or how to stop it. I have tried every method previously posted on stackoverflow. Here is the function that reads a data file and puts each line in a hashmap.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> readDataFromFile(){
    this.openFileForReading();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    try{
        String line;

        while ((line = this.reader.readLine()) != null){ 

            while (!(line.equals(""))){

                if (line.equals("[type = book]")){
                    HashMap<String, String> data= new HashMap<>();
                    line = this.reader.readLine();

                    while (!(line.equals(""))){<----this is where the null exception error is

                        String tokens[] = line.split("=");
                        data.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
                        System.out.println(tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1]);
                        line = this.reader.readLine();

                    }
                   list.add(data);
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (IOException exception) {
        list = null;
        System.err.println("(FileIO): " + exception);            
    }
    // Close the file when we have finished reading or if an error occurs
    finally {
        try {
            this.reader.close();                
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.err.println("(FileIO): " + exception);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I then run it in main with this:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {                                
    FileIO fileIO = new FileIO(DATA_FILE_PATH);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    list = fileIO.readDataFromFile();

}
```

> ```
> run:
> ```
>
> callnumber   �QA76.73.J38S265� 
>   authors   �Walter Savitch, Kenrich Mock� 
>   title   �Absolute Java� 
>   publisher   �Addison-Wesley� 
>   year   �2009�
>   callnumber   �P98.C6116�
>   title   �Computational Linguistics�
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   organization   �Association for Computational Linguistics�
>       at librarysearch.FileIO.readDataFromFile(FileIO.java:160)
>   year   �2008�
>       at librarysearch.FileIO.main(FileIO.java:405)
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

I wrote in the code where the error occurs. Why is this happening? I don't understand, if anyone saavy could please help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the entire exception with stack trace.

Comment: Post the full exception tree

Comment: First thing to do: read the exception stack trace (or post it if you can't understand it). Error messages are intended to be read. They tell you what and where the problem is. By not reading them, you're shooting yourself in the foot, and what could be solved in 10 seconds taks days to be solved.

Comment: nvm i will edit my main post

Comment: Having 3 nested `while` loops and an `if` statement depend on one single variable is going to cause problems. You're not even using some of the inputs you're receiving.

Comment: You readLine twice (actually thrice but you never reach the third invocation), once in the outermost while-loop's parens, once inside it. The second time you don't do a null check...

Comment: edit your question and add it there.  Also, it seems like "line" is null as you try to read in another line from this.reader (whatever that is) but you don't check for null.

Comment: line = this.reader.readLine(); could return null

Comment: Try this `while (!("".equals(line)))` to avoid NPE.

Comment: Does the last line of the file equal "[type = book]"? Because then you will probably get a NPE (assuming you are using a BufferedReader).

Comment: The file is like so
[type = book]
author = fsffsf
title = ssfsf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're consuming a new line without checking for null:

```
 HashMap<String, String> data= new HashMap<>();
 line = this.reader.readLine(); <--- i mean this, and line can be null

 while (!(line.equals(""))){<----this is where the null exception error is
```

I give you a general advise:

**Never** compare a String variable against a String literal in this way:

```
if (myStringWhichCanBeNull.equals("my literal which is never null")) // ...
```

but **always** like this:

```
if ("my literal which is never null".equals(myStringWhichCanBeNull)) // ...
```

In many cases you will avoid NPE and have more robust code!

(I don't say that in this case this had saved your live...)

Comment: This worked! sort of. I added a while (line != null) before line.equals(") and it now doesnt give an error but stops at the first blank line

Answer (score 1):

```
line = this.reader.readLine();

while (!(line.equals(""))) {
```

You're reading a line, and then don't check if it's null before calling `equals()` on it. It will be null if there is nothing to read anymore in the file, as documented in the javadoc of the `readLine()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 line = this.reader.readLine();
```

probably returns null on line 13 (unlucky for some)

then you call .equals on it

So maybe add some more error checking

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the result of [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) for null everywhere you call the method.  As the Java API documentation states, `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

Your outer loop checks for null, but you have additional nested loops which perform additional reads but don't check for null.  Consider restructuring your code and modifying your logic so you're only using one loop instead of nesting several loops to perform the readLine() operations.  Otherwise, you will need to add more null checks and either add break statements or modify your loop conditions, which may make the code more difficult to read.